# Failed to run diagnostics: ! error in callr subprocess

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I just installed the R extension for VSCode and followed the steps provided in the getting started section on this page : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r

I wrote a very basic R code to test the functionality of everything, the code which I have attached below:

```
num1<-2
num2<-3
print(num1+num2)
```

The following problem always shows up :

```
Failed to run diagnostics: ! error in callr subprocess
Caused by error in `namespaceExport(ns, exports)`:
! undefined exports: str_sub<-, boundary, coll, fixed, invert_match, regex, str_c, str_conv, str_count, str_detect, str_dup, str_ends, str_extract, str_extract_all, str_flatten, str_glue, str_glue_data, str_interp, str_length, str_locate, str_locate_all, str_match, str_match_all, str_order, str_pad, str_remove, str_remove_all, str_replace, str_replace_all, str_replace_na, str_sort, str_split, str_split_fixed, str_squish, str_starts, str_sub, str_subset, str_to_lower, str_to_sentence, str_to_title, str_to_upper, str_trim, str_trunc, str_view, str_view_all, str_which, str_wrap, word
```

It would be of a great help if I could receive some help on how to rectify this error.

Thanking You.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem when I was using a `lintr` -file in the project root. The problem was that I copied some content for that file from [here](https://lintr.r-lib.org/articles/lintr.html)  which resulted in a wrong formatting of that file.

The `.lintr` must conform a special format, which you can test, if you run `read.dcf(".lintr")` in the R-terminal.

My now working, right formate `.lintr` -file looks like so:
[image]

- Make sure that the last `)` aligns exactly with the text above.
- The file must have end with an empty line.

More info also [here](https://lintr.r-lib.org/articles/lintr.html)